# Restarting of Windows development machine and losing code

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, domain, automatic-updates

Not sure which exact forum this question fits in, aplogies in advance if this is the wrong forum (please let me know the correct one).

Our Windows domain joined Windows 10 machines which we use for coding have been restarting without notice to install latest updates. We typically have several projects open simultaneously. Needless to say it's frustrating to find everything closed and Visual Studio asking to restore some code from autosaved files.

Question: In a Windows domain group policies for updates, is it not possible to prompt a user to save their work before restarting? I know for a fact it's possible on my home Windows machine.

Comment: Our domain admins send out updates for us developers around 11pm.  We are warned the day of to not leave our dev environment open, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Windows > Deployment > Update Windows 10 > Manage device restarts after updates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-restart)

Set active hours. Save work before active hours end. Configure restart delays and notifications if desired.